# Regex query: any from list bracketing central term

Tags: regex

Apologies for the ugly question title: I'm not really sure how to phrase this succinctly, and apologies if this has been asked before: I couldn't find any references.

So, I would like to create a regex query, made up of three parts:

```
1) [ABCD]

2) (CD)+|(DC)+

3) [BADC]
```

The problem is that this query will of course match any of ABCD at the beginning and end. What I would like is for the beginning and end to be related, so that if it only matches if the substring begins with A and ends with B, begins with B and ends with A etc (as in the ordering in the [] above).

I.e., I do not want to match ACDCDA, but I do want to match ACDCDB.

I know this is possible by stringing together four queries of the form:

```
([A](CD)+|(DC)+[B])|([B](CD)+|(DC)+[A]) etc
```

but this quickly becomes ugly and hard to read. Is there a more elegant way to do this with regular expressions?

Edit: to answer questions in comments:
Language is python, although ideally I'm looking for a general regex expression so that this can work elsewhere if necessary.

Additional examples:

Acceptable:

CCDD

DCDC

DDCC

ACDB

ACDCDCDCDB

BCDA

Not acceptable:

ACDA

ACDCDA

ACDDCA

CCDC

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Can you please post additional acceptable and unacceptable strings?

Comment: `DDCD` should not be in the accepted patterns :)

Comment: Thank you! Too many letters and the eyes begin to blur...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following (shortest I could write):

```
((?=^A.*B$)|(?=^B.*A$)|(?=^C.*D$)|(?=^D.*C$))[ABCD]((CD)+|(DC)+)[ABCD]
```

Explanation:

- `(?=^A.*B$)` assert if pattern starts with A then it should end with B

Similarly for others..

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yM1dM7/6)

Comment: This pattern match also to `ACDDCblablablaB`. You need change it to `((?=^A.*B$)|(?=^B.*A$)|(?=^C.*D$)|(?=^D.*C$))(?=^.((CD)+|(DC)+).$)`, shorter and work/